# The username you provided is not allowed to use the text-based Tomcat Manager (error 403) when deploying on remote Tomcat8 using Jenkins

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a WAR on the remote Tomcat (Remote Machine) using Jenkins deploy to container Plugin.
I have done the following configuration in tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="deployer" password="deployer" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,admin" />
```

I have setup the proper username password and port in Jenkins deployer container plugin. The setup is working fine for the local Tomcat.
But for remote Tomcat I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username you provided is not allowed to use the text-based Tomcat Manager (error 403) at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:555)

at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686) 
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699) 
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)

... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://1.203.190.5:8080/manager/text/list 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:544) ... 19 more
```

Comment: Probably the entered user doesn't have Read/Write access on the Remote Machine.

Comment: I checked the access. User has access.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This seems to be a Jenkins bug but I got around the problem by setting up following configuration in Tomcat:

Edit the file /webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml:

Previous:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>
```

Change this file to comment the Value:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
  <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
    -->
</Context>
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: There isn't a bug with Jenkins.  By default Tomcat does not allow access to the manager from external machines, i.e. other than localhost.  This just disables that restriction.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I get

    jenkins-host> curl http://tomcat-host:8090/manager/text/list -u deployer
    Enter host password for user 'deployer': thepassword
    OK - Listed applications for virtual host [localhost]
    /:running:0:ROOT
    /manager:running:0:manager

but "The username you provided is not allowed to use the text-based Tomcat Manager (error 403)" using just the same username through jenkins deploy plugin.

What can be done to get 200 OK through jenkins? Checked: when password or username is bad, i get 401 not 403 from curl.

Comment: In my case the issue was that I did not provide the port number in the Tomcat URL field. Instead of http://hostname I have put http://hostname:8080 and it worked well.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue while deploying artifact to tomcat with jenkins via container plugin,
Solution:- i have added manager-script and manager-gui in the roles of the user and provide the full access to webapps/* directory. It helps me to deploy the artifact successfully and able to view it with manager-app.

Comment: Thanks , this is **simple solution**.

Answer (score 5):

My OS : Debain 10

I solved this by editing file `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and added `manager-script` role

```
  <role rolename="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the jenkins IP address to the valve.

You need to update : **/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml**. Because it allows only localhost. If you know the specific hostname or IP, you can add it replacing XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX by the IP address.
It's realy important to keep the security in place.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" />
</Context>
```

After that, you need to restart tomcat.

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh && $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works simply create another user in tomcat-users.xml file with magnager-script role assigned and set this user credential to jenkins .

In tomcat-users.xml file

```
<tomcat-users>
<user  username="deployuser" password="deployuser" roles="manager-script" />
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui" />
</tomcat-users>
```

[image: deploying to tomcat from jenkins]

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 9, you don't need to add any manager-XXX roles. All you have to do is add the users and and assign the manager-gui (for GUI access) and manager-script (for access like Jenkins deployment ).
Also, make sure to edit the file **/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml**, either to comment out valve or define appropriate reg ex for **allow** attribute

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: 
We need to update : \webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml. Bcs it allows only localhost. If you know the specific hostname or IP, you can add.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
         -->
</Context>
```

Step 2:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui, manager-script"/>
```

[image]

Deployment went successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing the username to "admin" should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

First do this,

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!-- 
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  -->
</Context>
```

if you are still facing issue means,
add

`manager-script`

to your role of whichever user you are looking for it will work.